# copy multiple columns from file1 of an excel sheet to other column in file2 excel sheet using python

Tags: python, excel

I need to copy from file1, from column A2 and B2 and their entire column and paste the data into column B from B2 and C from C2 down in file 2 using python.

Rows A and B on file 1 copied and pasted into Column B and C in File 2.

```
import openpyxl as xl
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import pandas as pd
import os
import dateutil.parser as parser
import datetime as datetime


objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = True
objWorksheetobjExcel.Workbooks.Open("File 1.xlsx")
objWorkbook2 = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("File 2.xlsx")

objWorksheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
objWorksheet.Activate

objRange = objWorkSheet.Range("A2:B2").EntireColumn
objWorkSheet.Range("A2:B2").EntireColumn.Copy
objWorkSheet2.Paste objWorkSheet2.Range("B4")

objWorksheet2 = objWorkbook2.Worksheets(1)
objWorksheet.Activate

objRange = objWorkSheet2.Range("A1")
objRange = objWorkSheet2.Range("B1")
objWorksheet.Paste(objRange)
```

Comment: What have you tried till now? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @KartikShandilya, i am new to python so just currently trying to find a basic script that allows me to copy the first two columns of file 1 and paste it into columns B1 and C1 in File 2.